# Python None and numpy commands in Julia

Tags: python, numpy, julia

In some of the python scripts I use:

```
x = None
```

What would be the equivalent in Julia

Also in some numpy code I have I would use the following to coerce data to an array:

```
y = np.asarray(x)
```

Does julia have a similar function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `None`, use `nothing`, e.g.

```
x = nothing
x + 1  # Error, meaningless
```

As for your second question, I don't think there is an equivalent. What precisely did you want to coerce into an array? In Julia there isn't a distinction between arrays and lists like there is in Python/Numpy.

Comment: I don't think `asarray` maps to `vec`, as `np.asarray([[1,2],[3,4]])` would produce a `(2,2)`-shaped ndarray from the list, not a `(4,)`-shaped one.

Comment: Thats true, it doesn't do what I thought it did! I've edited my answer.